# can't publish APK to production track google api v3 androidpublish

Tags: python, google-api, google-play, google-api-client

Currently my production track in the google Play Console has my existing application, using python with the official google-api-client from `pipy` I was able to authenticate and upload my application using the `edits` API following along from [google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits/) and using the following resource as an API reference [offical api reference](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/androidpublisher_v3.edits.html)

the problem is when before I send the final commit, when sending `edits().tracks().update(packageName, editId, track, resource)` the return object is empty and it shouldn't be, along with my application not being set to the production track. I can find the uploaded APK in **Artifact Library** but it will not appear in the production track. Any help would be appreciated

```
trackUpdateInfo = {
    u'releases': [
        {
            u'name': u"3.0.3",
            u'status': u"completed",
            u'versionCodes': [30001]
        }
    ]
}

info = playApi.edits().tracks().update(packageName=bundleName,
                                        editId=persistentEditId,
                                        track='production',
                                        body=trackUpdateInfo).execute()
```

and to commit  I would run the following

```
 commitStatus = playApi.edits().commit(packageName = bundleName, editId = persistentEditId).execute()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had changed a lot of things, I'm unsure what the nail in the coffin was to fix this; However, I believe I was missing the `track` property in `trackUpdateInfo` along with having everything done during 1 `edit` instead of having 2 separate operations. Originally I uploaded, committed started a new edit and updated the tracks but that didn't work. I put all the operations in 1 edit and I was able to get the upload to go into the production or beta track.